# How to use Session in APIController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an APIController that stores a `List<Cart>` value and I want the list item to persist and use Session to get and post item into the list in order to be pulled into a view to show the cart item.

I am not quite sure where to use session and how to create it as I am new to Session.

APIController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using fyp.Models;


namespace fyp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Cart")]
    public class CartAPIController : Controller
    {
        private List<Cart> cart = new List<Cart>()
        {
            new Cart {  CartId = 1,
                    FoodId = 6,
                    FoodName = "Beef & Tendon with Noodle",
                    quantity = 1,
                    price = 7},
            new Cart {  CartId = 1,
                    FoodId = 1,
                    FoodName = "Curry Beef Gravy with Beef Noodle",
                    quantity = 2,
                    price = 6}
        };


        // GET: api/<controller>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(cart);
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(Cart cart)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this.cart.Add(
                    new Cart
                    {
                        CartId = cart.CartId,
                        FoodId = cart.FoodId,
                        FoodName = cart.FoodName,
                        quantity = cart.quantity,
                        price = cart.price
                    });
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The items inside `List<Cart>` is there just for testing purpose but how can I implement an empty list inside a session?

Comment: API is totally stateless. There is no session between front end and Api Controller. You should use MVC controller not Api Contoller.

Comment: But I need this data in JSON format in order to show it real time in jquery, any alternatives?

Comment: you can use localstorage of browser

Answer (score -1):

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) gives information on how to use `session` in your asp.net application.

It seems basically you replace your existing `this.cart` with `Session["cart"]`, so your Post becomes something like:

```
    public IActionResult Post(Cart cart)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["cart"].Add(
                new Cart
                {
                    CartId = cart.CartId,
                    FoodId = cart.FoodId,
                    FoodName = cart.FoodName,
                    quantity = cart.quantity,
                    price = cart.price
                });
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How session work with api where api is totally stateless?

Comment: I believe that basically, the `session` variable is seralised into a cookie and passed to the UI, so in effect, the state is in a cookie that is passed to the server when posting the page.

Comment: No brother. It's not possible for API but MVC.